# React-router-dom link route to target page after refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to navigate to different pages use react-router-dom {Link}... But when I clicked each link, the browser stays on the current page. I need to refresh the web page to go to the target page.

[Image for my Route in index.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjnDT.png)
[Image for my Link in CourseRow.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlsLJ.png)

```
            <td>
                <Link to='/course/2'>
                    {this.props.course.title}
                </Link>

            </td>
```

How can I navigate to the target page without refresh

Thanks

Comment: have you setup it correctly?

Comment: I not very sure about setting it up correctly, I can navigate to the target page after refreshing the page. And I didn't get any error message from the console..

Comment: your path and you router mismatch, whiteboard and whiteBoard with B and b

Comment: are you exporting CourseRow?

Comment: @AngelSalazar Yes I do export courseRow

Comment: @F.bernal Do you mean the link and Component?

Comment: can you confirm if you are using redux?

Comment: @AngelSalazar NOPE I haven't started redux yet

Comment: is your component WhiteBoard ok? did you see any error in console? Where is course route defined? I think your course route is not well defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can see a basic setup

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Link to="/first">Go first</Link> <Link to="/second">Go second</Link>
      <Route path="/first" exact component={First} />
      <Route path="/second" exact component={Second} />
    </Router>
  );
}

function First() {
  return <div>First</div>;
}

function Second() {
  return <div>Second</div>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thx I set it up correctly when I click the link the target address appears in my browser address bar, but just don't navigate to that address.

Comment: Hey, I justed added two pics in my description. I am trying to click on each course name and navigate to each course. Right now, it should take me to a blank page. Because I am following a web tutorial, so I am sure I don't need to refresh my page to reach the target page.

Comment: if the URL gets updated and navigation does not happen, you probably need to use the withRouter HOC, because you might have a shouldComponentUpdate that returns false somewhere, it happens to me when using Redux + React Router DOm